# How to merge two videos, so that the scale of the video takes up 50% of the size of the output video

Tags: ffmpeg, ffmpeg-python, pyffmpeg

How to merge two videos, so that the scale of the video takes up 50% of the size of the output video.

For example I need to merge two videos so that one half of the video takes up 50% of the output video size from the top and the other half takes up 50% of the output video size from the bottom.

i.e. to divide both video halves in the output video!

Example of such video youtube.com/shorts/InBFBwkUsgI

I tried to ask questions GPT but did not get a normal answer, that is, I do not know how to implement it in general heard that you can implement through vstack

Comment: `ffmpeg -i top.mp4 -i bottom.mp4 -lavfi vstack out.mp4`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.